# Is it possible to see the data model diagram in vstudio when I use EF Code First?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Once I create my data model using Code First, I would like to see it diagrammed, is it possible? For example, when I use Database First, I generate an edmx. Is there something similar for Code First? Thank you

Comment: Visual Studio Enterprise is a requirement I think

Comment: Thank you. I have the professional version but I can not find where to see it.

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a new project for the same database , that uses model first?  Just use the project to display the model, not update it.

If you are using SQL Server you can use the Database Diagrams from within Management Studio.  Unfortunately I can't see the diagrams in the SQL Server Object Explorer in Visual Studio.